# show hide content from Div, show first by default

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was looking for some code to show / hide divs according to item selected from the menu. I found this code, but only works having all divs hidden from start.  Could somebody help to modify it to show first option by default?

Here is the fiddle I found http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/M3ZhV/

I have tried to toggle the view, but it not working :)

```
var curPage="";
$("#menu a").click(function() {
    if (curPage.length) { 
        $("#"+curPage).toggle();
    }
    curPage=$(this).data("page");
    $("#"+curPage).toggle();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first option to show by default, add this to the top (where `curPage` is)

```
var curPage="";

if(!curPage){
    $('#page1').show()
  curPage = "page1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kalob, this works perfect :)  Also... could you please explain me how the code is using  `curPage.length`   I have a general idea, but to understand better this. I'm just learning :)  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Basically if you do an `if` statement on a string in Javascript, it will return `false` if the string is empty and `true` if it has something in it, and if you do it on a number `0` will always return `false`, `true` if it is greater. This is checking the length of the `curPage` string, you could just do `if(curPage)` and it will do the same thing,

Comment: @KalobPorter Thanks :)  Makes absolutely sense

Answer (score 1):

A slight revision of your current code:

```
$(function() {
$('#page1').show();
var curPage="page1";
  $("#menu a").click(function() {
     if (curPage.length) { 
         $("#"+curPage).hide();
     }
     curPage=$(this).data("page");
     $("#"+curPage).show();
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rzrsLf8/)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```js
$(function() {

$("a[data-page^='page'").click(function() {
$("div[id^='page']").hide();
 var page=$(this).attr('data-page');
 $("div[id='"+page+"']").show();
});
});
```

```css
    .content { display:none;}
    .content:nth-child(1)
    {
      display:block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="link1"><a href="#" data-page="page1">Topic One</a>
            </li>
            <li id="link2"><a href="#" data-page="page2">Topic Two</a>
            </li>
            <li id="link3"><a href="#" data-page="page3">Topic Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="page1" class="content">
             <h1>Show Page1</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="content">
             <h1>Show Page2</h1>

        </div>
        <div id="page3" class="content">
             <h1>Show Page3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are welocme